# NVIDIA Prime Issue

Tags: nvidia

hey guys having a problem with NVIDIA Prime, unable to switch to NVIDIA Performance Mode. Its a setting on Nvidia X Server Settings. I;ve got a discrete card and a built in Intel chip. Using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Any error code? Is the option just grayed out? Do you have the proprietary drivers for the card?

Comment: Whenever i try to change it through the GUI on X Server Settings theres just a pop up with a red cirlce. i can screenshot this if you like?

Comment: The propriety drivers : http://imgur.com/7IEXxAw

Comment: This happens when trying to change to NVIDIA: http://imgur.com/XDP7PZv

Comment: I can't see the second image.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem. Installed the 331 proprietary driver, but can't switch to it.